# azure app service Installation error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/opt/Kudu/local/npm-cache'

Tags: node.js, strapi

I am trying to sync the app service which is linked with the bitbucket. when i try to sync data from the bitbucket its showing me below error
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
error /tmp/8da38dcb36cf63a/node_modules/sharp: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
Arguments:
Directory: /tmp/8da38dcb36cf63a/node_modules/sharp
Output:
sharp: Installation error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/opt/Kudu/local/npm-cache'
sharp: Are you trying to install as a root or sudo user? Try again with the --unsafe-perm flag
sharp: Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
warning "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions > @strapi/helper-plugin
anyone can help me ?
what's  the solution
[image]

Comment: Facing similar issue. Please let us know if resolved

Answer (score 5):

The problem is it does `npm install` on the npm-cache folder, but it does not have rights to do so.

I resolved it with creating a new "Application Setting" on Azure `PRE_BUILD_COMMAND` with value: `mkdir ./npmcache && npm config set cache ./npmcache`.

This command is executed before the yarn/npm install + build. It create a new folder, having write rights on it. Then it set this folder as the npm cache folder.

Comment: This did it for me, thanks for sharing. It's worth noting that "Application Setting" also translates to "Environment Variable" on other platforms, e.g. Vercel.